# change json field type while read by pyarrow

Tags: python, json, pyarrow

I have one field json and in the end I want to convert it to parquet, so I need to change types:

```
{"SomeDecimal": "44444"}
```

and code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import json
    
schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('SomeDecimal', pa.float32())
])
    
one = pa.json.read_json('sample.json', parse_options=json.ParseOptions(explicit_schema=schema))
```

According to documentation, if I understand correctly that should change valueDecimal type from string to float. But it doesn't works.

I got the error:

```
ArrowInvalid: JSON parse error: Column(/SomeDecimal) changed from number to string in row 0
```

Why error says that I changed number to string?
What is wrong with that? I can't find solution for that error.

Answer (score 5):

Arrow can't interpret `"4444"` as a float32. It should be `4444`, without quote.

One work around would be to load the data as a string and cast it later:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import json
    
raw_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('SomeDecimal', pa.string())
])
processed_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('SomeDecimal', pa.float32())
])
    
raw_table = pa.json.read_json('sample.json', parse_options=json.ParseOptions(explicit_schema=raw_schema))
table = raw_table.cast(processed_schema)
```

Comment: ok! Thank you @0x26res. So actually I can create an only second schema, load JSON as default, and then create a second schema, and just cast the table. One extra question: property prepared second schema will allow me to change types in a struct?

Comment: yes you can cast nested struct types, but only since pyarrow 8.0.0